# Zoom function on images with fixed size in MS Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, photos

I have photos with dimensions 4160x3120 and 3120x4160. These photos are from modules of a machine. The modules are big parts which contain small subparts.

I'm making a word document where I describe these modules together with all the small subparts. My plan is to insert the photo of the machine module and keep the picture on a fixed size. In order to see all the details in the photo the reader should be able to zoom in (and back out again) on a part of the picture.

This way I can make a clean document.

- Is this possible in Word 2010?
- If yes, how?
- If not, any other suggestions?

EDIT: Other suggestions still welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in Word 2010. Although it was added to later versions starting in [2013](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-s-new-in-Word-2013-3a9a927f-73ad-4ac5-910b-dfb12052d063) as Object Zoom.

Do not know of any alternatives for 2010 other than the [standard document zoom](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Zoom-in-or-out-of-a-document-presentation-or-worksheet-0a0ebbed-10e7-444b-b16b-6f0c090f8ec7).